# Moodle: Error In fetching capabilities of logged-in User

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

```
class block_add extends block_base {

function init() {
    $this->title = get_string('pluginname', 'block_add');

}

function applicable_formats() {
    return array('all' => true, 'tag' => false);
}

function specialization() {
    $this->title = isset($this->config->title) ? $this->config->title : get_string('newblock', 'block_add');
}

function instance_allow_multiple() {
    return true;
}

function get_content()
{

    global $USER, $DB;

    if ($this->content !== NULL) {
        return $this->content;
    }

    $this->content = new stdClass();
    $roles = $DB->get_records('role_capabilities',['userid'=>$USER->id]);->(// in this lines i am getting error "error readig from database")
    var_dump($roles);
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $this->content->footer .= "Role Id  = ".$role->contextid."</br>"."Context Id  = ".$role->contextid."</br>"."Permission  = ".$role->capability."</br>" ;
    }

}




function has_config() {return true;}
```

}

i am getting "error reading from database" idk why, i am trying to print all assigned capabilities of logged-in user (for example: Admin),i am newbie in php as well on Moodle

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73712257/edit) your question to include the error message _in full_, with a clear explanation of the line it's thrown at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `role_capabilities` table is for **role** capabilities not **user** capabilities, so there isn't a `userid` column

Capabilities (permissions) in Moodle is quite complex. There are capabilities at various levels (context) - site, category, course, module/activity, block, user. The capabilities are assigned to a role and a user is assigned to one or more roles. The capabilities can also be overridden. So it's not straightforward.

I'd suggest looking through `/lib/accesslib.php` at the various get functions to see if there an existing function that does what you want.

The list of capabilities will also be very long, so probably not suitable for a block.

You can see a list of capabilities for a user at

Site administration > Users > Permissions > Check system permissions

and a list of capabilities for a role at

Site administration > Users > Permissions > Capability overview